# MySQL query for duplicate contents

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get rid of the search of id's of certain column if more than 1 unique value is found based on the condition that another column's id is the same. 
IE:

```
col1 col2
1    33
1    33
1    33
2    33
2    33
```

So there are more than 1 unique value for col1 for col2 value of 33 only.

Is there a way we can return results for only 1 unique value and ignore the second unique value in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) could help

```
SELECT c1, c2 from XX GROUP BY c1, c2;
```

Comment: AKA `SELECT distinct c1.c2 FROM xx`